# Web api deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, json, xml, deserialization

I receive in a request from a web api project a parameter that represents the URL to a json or xml file.

What i have to do is to download this file, deserialize it and the process it.

In the past i was writting two individual methods :

- one method that was reading the file using linq to xml
- another method that reading the file using newtonsoft.json

I am wondering is there a way so that web api can deserialize automatically this url link / file for me ?

Comment: One way would be to create a ModelBinder and set the bindingContext.Model to the deserialized output in there

Comment: Use [System.Net.WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) to grab the JSON/XML file and then deserialize it using your library of choice in the Web API controller.